# Error is not accessedPylance en el nombre de una función en python

Tags: python, funciones, bucles

Esto haciendo un juego de ahorcado y al momento de llamar mi funcion obtenerIntento() me doy cuenta que anteriormente me da un error en entonces me dice que no esta definido.

Todavia no terminé el juego pero me trabe ahi, la funcion `obtenerIntento`, me retorna los intentos del jugador, que los obtenego dependiendo las letras probadas que es el parametro de mi función, pero al escribirlo en mi editor de codigo me aparece de un color más claro y no tengo idea porque.

La función tiene un loop while infinito en el que adentro hay varias condiciones, y luego lo que yo queria hacer es permitirle al jugador escribir una letra ,ahi es cuando establezco que los intentos van a comprender la funcion de intento y el parametro de la función va a tener las suma de las letras correctas e incorrectas que seria el totoal de intento.

Aca les dejo el codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
import random

img_ahorcado = ['''

      +---+
      |   |
          |
          |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''

      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
          |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''

      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
      |   |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''

      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|  |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''

      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''

      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
     /    |
          |
    =========''', '''
    
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
     / \  |
          |
    =========''']

palabras = ['grino youtube elefante camaleon cama mesa silla botella celular comptuadora lata serpiente cisne camaleon gorra lapicera lapiz cable monitor laptop juego auriculares cargador control'.split()]


def obtenerPalabra(palabras):
    # Esta funcion va a devolver una cadena al calzar de la lsita de cadenas pasada como argumento
    indice = random.randint(0, len(palabras) - 1)
    return palabras[indice]

def mostrarTablero(img_ahorcado, letrasIncorrectas, letrasCorrectas, palabra):
  print(img_ahorcado[len(letrasIncorrectas)])
  print()
  
  print("Letras incorrectas: ", end="")
  for letra in letrasIncorrectas:
    print(letra, end="")
    print()
    
  espacios = "_" * len(palabra)
  
  for i in range(len(palabra)):
    if palabra[i] in letrasCorrectas:
      espacios = espacios[i] + palabra[i] + espacios [i+1:]
      
  for letra in espacios: 
    print(letra, end="")
  print()
  
  def obtenerIntento(letrasProbadas):
    while True:
      print("Advina una letra") 
      intento = input()
      intento.lower() 
      if len(intento) != 1:
        print("Porfa capo introduce una letra")
      elif intento in letrasProbadas:
        print("Ya probaste esa letra campeon, elegi otra")
      elif intento not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        print('Ingresa una letra correcta, ingresaste cualquier cosa men')
      else:
        return intento
      
def jugarDeNuevo():
  print("Queres volver a jugar (s/n)")
  return input().lower.starswith('s')

print('A H O R C A D O ')
letrasIncorrectas = ''
letrasCorrectas = ''
palabra = obtenerPalabra()
juegoTerminado = False

while True:
  mostrarTablero(img_ahorcado, letrasIncorrectas, letrasCorrectas, palabra)
  
  # Permitirle al jugador escribri una letra
  intento = obtenerIntento(letrasIncorrectas + letrasCorrectas)
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Antes de poder ayudarte a ver donde está el error, es necesario que *indentes* correctamente el código! En python los bloques de código se definen por su indentación ya que no hay corchetes `{}` de inicio y fin de bloque. Por favor, utiliza una indentación **CONSTANTE Y CORRECTA**! A veces usas dos espacios, a veces tres... eso provoca que el código no funcione como crees que va a funcionar. Una vez arreglado puedes usar el botón [edit] para ponerlo en la pregunta.